# Target class [ClsFormulario] does not exist

Tags: laravel

He creado un formulario "por curiosear" para introducir datos y un controlador (aún no sé muy bien el porqué pero así vi la explicación). Al decirle *enviar* me sale

> **Target class [ClsFormulario] does not exist.**

WEB.PHP

```
"route::view('/formulario','formulario')->name('formulario');"
"route::post('/formulario','ClsFormulario@store');"
```

FORMULARIO.

```
"<form method="post">"

    "@csrf"

    "<input name="name" placeholder="Nombre..."><br>"
    "<input name="email" placeholder="Email..."><br>"
    "<input name="Asunto" placeholder="Asunto..."><br>"
    "<textarea name="Mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje..."></textarea><br>"
    "<button>Enviar</button>"

"</form>"
```

CLSFORMULARIO.PHP

```
"<?php"

"namespace App\Http\Controllers;"

"use Illuminate\Http\Request;"

"class ClsFormulario extends Controller"
"{
"    public function store()"
"        {"
"            return 'Procesar los datos';"
"        }"
"}"
```

Comment: ¿Por qué tu código tiene comillas?

Comment: Adhiero al comentario anterior. Además tenes errores de sintaxis, por ejemplo en [como declaras la ruta](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing). Y algo basico de html -> el formulario no tiene un atributo `action`. Te sugiero leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar tu pregunta y que sea mejor recibida.